# Multiple Keys are mapped to the same keypress

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

so I've been running into this issue where I bought a 3rd party keyboard and linux cannot properly figure out what the entire layout is. Right now the L/R Control, L/R Alt, and the "Windows" key are all mapped to Shift_L. I'm trying to figure out if I can remap them using their location on the keyboard. Looking at other similar questions I have used xev and found out the following info:

```
L Control
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x49a, subw 0x0, time 4433091, (78,36), root:(1423,88), 
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

L Alt
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x49a, subw 0x0, time 4485817, (4,134), root:(1349,186),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

R Control
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x49a, subw 0x0, time 4513012, (83,62), root:(1428,114),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

R Alt
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x49a, subw 0x0, time 4532271, (69,151), root:(1414,203),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Windows
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3a00001,
    root 0x49a, subw 0x0, time 4560554, (120,27), root:(1465,79),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'm wondering if the numbers in parentheses after "time ####" in the second line of each text is the position the key is in? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Before you try something complex, I'd advise you to first try out a proper keyboard model setting for your keyboard. Run the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and change the keyboard model.

Comment: My keyboard model isn't listed (that's how generic it is) I mean there is a name that could be construed as "DAMN" or "DMAN" and the only code on it doesn't yield any results in a google search

Comment: All models are not listed. The most commonly used option is "pc105". Try that, if it's not set already.

Comment: No dice. My Ctrl and Alt keys are still functioning as "Shift" keys

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you reboot after having set "pc105"?

Comment: Yup. Still nothing.

Comment: I see. Then this issue is above my head. Hopefully somebody else can help.